# Is this a correct 'Bare metal' motor driver?

Tags: mosfet, pwm, driver, motor-controller, mosfet-driver

I need to make a simple motor driver, I'm using a IRF510 and I wonder to know if this could work.

[image: schematic]

[The circuit - falstad simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAXEFFG7mqijx5+VKhBiEEYQjzAFiCbClwoo0EpkWzK2BDkgQwcEABMGAMwCGAVwA2HNgHNuw7gkKuRQkWLYAnL25eILAaPioaDEg2ACVwcNEQPEEBKG5aKiQxdQQA4L5ecUSi9KiY+J8EwrdWNRy0sHr0mDyLIJ4+AUEQ5XBobNgUZ0zUyJNMZorR8CEZ4k8G8SncthowJG7ZkS20X1zwdQ2jwch62CQJNgB7EE9CCMzSJ8IxaEe1T2w2IA)

**UPDATE**

I added the freewhelling diode as recommended by Tony Stewart and the design worked correctly.

Comment: Please include an image of your circuit so we don't have to click a link to see it.

Comment: lasb3tas - I have used the Falstad "export as image" feature to make an image of the schematic and inserted that into the question. If you update the simulation, please also update that image in the question. Thanks.

Comment: FYI "Bare metal" doesn't mean no software or firmware. It means firmware that interacts directly with the hardware through the registers. Since you have no software here so its not bare metal anything.

Comment: DKNguyen, well, Bare metal doesn't just mean that, maybe I got the usage wrong, but I meant to say 'rough'.

Comment: Adding a reverse biased zener on FET gate to ground rated at just above max drive voltge will clamp inductive spikes from drain by Miller capacitance. This can add substantial robustness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that’s a ***burnt*** metal driver with kV on the drain.

A push pull driver or half bridge works best as the impedance is low to control the flyback voltage.

But **[here I’ve shown](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjATCAMB00IQVhBWAOaBmMA2CALOgJwFIS5gEhLQ0gFY0CmAtGGAFAAuIW01QnSxZcqAnTpgQ7XLGILFxAOzoKEbDILylisMSzFNYBCAAmzAGYBDAK4AbbpwDmfUaiRiRYiOnQwYTgAnNx9CUPACajoCZWhOACUPHwlUcKEAqFSUSRhYJGC%20AXE6CE8SgNj4pO9I6lqOKFzUyADJfM5LCIhwiVLwrCgwfNQXBlMysT7UPzbE8alfBZBiMWbFtryCgjAUach-aY1-dpRpOF28y7hoJvgUHM4saksAdzMggHsABwAdAEc4JgxNJhsoqFhyOh9L4TAgIGxlAFhtCIMp%20OgdoMCEZlE0aJwzAwiKhoIcSQdUCA3h8fgCgdBcJxXsT-JT9ksuCyov5jss%20RBOBImARcIJssQoPxoiBcAB9MVy5RysCQghouVIOUXbUqlWwMpygBiAFEACpCzSi6hUahISWkk7gaAKghKlVqjUaOVYA26sCauUAEQAlp8LJaRWK%20FB7VBVgFiK73aqkOrlVqdS6A5g5QBZT7cT5BZn88pHFqR1B48BTUyYALoZPK1PqrUI1gtthJ7Oa324dBxYiQOUAZVs32%209gAnpxPrLZTKJApSbLYDKoF5OEA)** with a power diode that has some benefits but still very lossy.

Also I increased the Beta 20m which results here with Rdson=10 ohms to beta=5 for the Nch Fet to reduces the RdsOn to 0.6 ohms.

You didn't tweak the parameters so it only rotates the motor with milli-RPM with armature R=1ohm and dumps all the heat in the FET.

Comment: Thank you Tony for the reply. So completely I forgot the diode. I know that this is not the best possible driver but I need it pretty fast.